# What happens to bounties when a question is moved to another Stack Exchange site?

Tags: discussion, reputation, bounty

Just wondering what happens to the reputation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell the rep the answer gained after winning a bounty get's migrated along with it.

If you're referring to moderators migrating a question with a bounty attached to it, this bounty has to be removed (thus returning to the user who asked the question) before migration.

Comment: Ah, yes, that was my question. I answered a question with a 200 bounty and it was migrated to Severfault :) I was just kind of curious to if the rep just disappeared or was refunded.

Comment: I suspected that was the cause, I removed the bounty and migrated it to Server Fault, because it was likely to get you a better answer for free!

Comment: Totally understandable :) Was just curious.